# Best solution for "Array chaining"

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, php-5.3

For my project I wrote a small config class that loads its data from a .ini file. It overwrites the magic __get() method in order to provide simplified access to the (read only) config values.

Example config.ini.php:

```
;<?php exit; ?>
[General]
auth = 1
user = "halfdan"

[Database]
host = "127.0.0.1"
```

My config class (singleton pattern - simplified here) looks like this:

```
class Config {
    protected $config = array();

    protected function __construct($file) {
        // Preserve sections
        $this->config = parse_ini_file($file, TRUE);
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->config[$name];
    }
}
```

Loading the config would create an array structure like this:

```
array(
  "General" => array(
    "auth" => 1,
    "user" => "halfdan"
  ),
  "Database" => array(
    "host" => "127.0.0.1"
  )
)
```

It's possible to access the first level of the array by doing `Config::getInstance()->General`, and the values using `Config::getInstance()->General['user']`. What I really want though is being able to access all configuration variables by doing `Config::getInstance()->General->user` (syntactic sugar). The array is not an object and the "->" isn't defined on it, so this simply fails.

I thought of a solution and would like to get some public opinion about it:

```
class Config {
  [..]
  public function __get($name) {
    if(is_array($this->config[$name])) {
      return new ConfigArray($this->config[$name]);
    } else {
      return $this->config[$name];
    }
  }
}

class ConfigArray {
  protected $config;

  public function __construct($array) {
    $this->config = $array;
  }

  public function __get($name) {
    if(is_array($this->config[$name])) {
      return new ConfigArray($this->config[$name]);
    } else {
      return $this->config[$name];
    }
  }
}
```

This would allow me to chain my configuration access. As I'm using PHP 5.3 it might also be a good idea to let ConfigArray extend [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) (SPL is activated per default in 5.3).

Any suggestions, improvements, comments?

Comment: A bare ArrayObject would be my choice if you really want to swap `[]` for `->`, I am however not that bothered to alter it that way. Creating a _new_ object every time it is requested would be a bother though, I'd walk the array recursively and modify the arrays to arrayobjects only once.

Comment: @Wrikken: True, will change that behaviour in a real implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements of your `$this->config` array are also instances of your `Config` class, then it works.

The [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) has a similar component they call [Zend_Config](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.html).  You can [download](http://framework.zend.com/download/overview) the source and examine how they implemented it.  They didn't have to go all the way to extending `ArrayObject`.

The [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html) class has similar usage and it does extend `ArrayObject`.  The code for Zend_Registry is somewhat simpler as a result.

Comment: Looking at Zend_Config::__construct: They do `new self($value, ..)` for deeper array dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want array chaining in PHP, you should really take a look into [Chain](https://github.com/cocur/chain). It's a really small project were you can use chaining methods like `filter` and `count` like you are coding Java!

```
$arr = array_filter(
    array_map(
        function ($v) { return rand(0, $v); },
        array_fill(0, 10, 20)
    ),
    function ($v) { return $v & 1; }
);
```

becomes

```
$chain = Chain::fill(0, 10, 20)
    ->map(function ($v) { return rand(0, $v); })
    ->filter(function ($v) { return $v & 1; });
```

Awesome right?
More info you can find on [this blog](https://florian.ec/articles/chain-better-arrays-in-php/).